# Table row data is not being accessed under table body in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to access the table row data which is under the table body.

**Following is my HTML:**

```HTML
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="confirmationNotificationPanel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Patient Confirmation Notifications</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" onclick="createConfirmationNotification()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add New</button>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <tbody id="confirmationNotificationTableBody">
        **<tr id="confirmationNotification49" data-id="49">**
            <td style="width: 180px;">
                <select id="confirmationNotificationSource49" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <option value="CALL">CALL</option>
                    <option value="SMS">SMS</option>
                    <option value="EMAIL">EMAIL</option>
                    <option value="APP">APP/SMS</option>
                    <option value="WHATSAPP">WHATSAPP/SMS</option>
                </select>
            </td>
```

I only want to get the data-id value of the table row. I am using the CSS Extractor but not able to access that data-id value. I also tried with other extractors but not able to access the same.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve the approaches will differ.

An example setup of the [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) which will return `data-id` attribute for [`tr` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp) having `id` of `confirmationNotificationSource49` will be something like:

- Selector: `tr[id=confirmationNotification49]`
- Attribute: `data-id`

Demo (assumes "CSS Selector Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener):

[image]

More information: [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitri T 
but the id value is dynamic. I mean to say is that If I delete this id and create a new record, in that case, the value of it will be different. How to access that id dynamically?

Comment: If only `49` is dynamic you can amend the expression to look for row ids which [**start with**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) `confirmationNotification`, in this case the Selector would be `tr[id^=confirmationNotification]`

Comment: It is not working showing match count 0.

Comment: I cannot help without seeing how you configured JMeter, for me it [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZUff.png), I used [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide) to respond with the data you provided and the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to visualize the result of the CSS selector